# how to get text inside div with content label tag?

Tags: text, protractor, element

How can I get text "2.5" in the html code below in protractor?

[HTML script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQylb.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text of a element using **element(locator).getText()**. You can use below code snippet:

```
   var  targetElement=element(by.css("ul>li:nth-child(5)"));
   targetElement.getText().then(function (txt) {
        var textToSplit=txt.split(":");
        console.log("Text is : "+textToSplit[1]);
    });
```